# shared_ptr not defined when including from managed code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, shared-ptr

I'm trying to write a managed wrapper (C++/CLI) around an unmanaged C++ static library and am having two problems:

1. The unmanaged library uses `std::shared_ptr` in its headers. `<memory>` is included, and the header compiles as part of an unmanaged project. When I include this header in the managed project, however, I receive this error:

   error C2039: 'shared_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'
2. How do I access the `Values` collection of a `SortedDictionary<K, V>` from C++/CLI? I cannot seem to find any examples of the proper syntax, and the C#-style syntax does not compile.

Code for #1:

```
// 1>Dummy.h(10): error C2039: 'shared_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'
#pragma once

#pragma managed(push, off)

#include <memory>

class Foo {};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

#pragma managed(pop)


using namespace System;

namespace Dummy {

    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        Class1(FooPtr);
    };
}
```

Comment: hi hi, cool that you found the error. Even if it's off-topic. The documentation state, that every #pragma managed(push, off) should have happened after the includes, which is obviously not possible for third-party-libraries but for STL headers possible. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer here: [Edit $(IncludePath) "macro" in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349378/edit-includepath-macro-in-visual-studio-2010)

Visual Studio 2010 is including the headers from Visual Studio 2008, which do not have `shared_ptr`.

The exact resolution is described [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/600591-need-help-visual-studio-2010-insists-on-compiling-vs2008-sources/). The Platform Toolset on the General tab defaulted to `vs90`. Changing this to `vs100` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

shared_ptr lives in `<memory>` not `<functional>`.  Make it look similar to this:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include <memory>
#include "yourUnmanagedLibrary.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
```

Second question (ask only one please):

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic; 
...
    SortedDictionary<int, String^>^ coll = gcnew SortedDictionary<int, String^>;
    coll->Add(1, "one");
    coll->Add(0, "zero");
    for each (String^ value in coll->Values) {
        Console::WriteLine(value);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had mistyped in the question. I am including `<memory>` and still having the exact same issue. I also already have the `#pragma managed` statements exactly as demonstrated.

Comment: I cannot see your screen from here.  Post something that we can look at.

Comment: Code added. Created a new Class Library project and placed this in the generated header file.

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  Is the [visual-studio-2010] tag accurate?

Comment: Yes it is. Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. I don't believe I've installed SP1 yet. Perhaps I will give that a try.

Comment: Service Pack 1 did not change the issue. The test code still fails with the same error.

Comment: The #include for `<memory>` is including the file from VS2008 for some reason. Looks like the default include path points to the wrong directory.

Comment: Well, that's going to cause mayhem and misery.

Comment: It already has! I've been banging my head on this for two hours. Still trying to find the exact resolution to the problem aside from hard-coding the correct paths in the project file.