# Unusual error when compiling with iostream?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-c++-2010

So if I add iostream (VS 2010 express) I get these errors, can't find much on google, any ideas, didn't used to be like this, a I have is this...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build, I get the following error messages:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  stdafx.cpp
  test.cpp
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(535): error C2039: 'get' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(535): error C2873: 'get' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(536): error C2039: 'tuple_element' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(536): error C2873: 'tuple_element' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(537): error C2039: 'tuple_size' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(537): error C2873: 'tuple_size' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(236): error C2039: 'hexfloat' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(236): error C2873: 'hexfloat' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Try to change the order of `includes`.

Comment: Have you tried removing `#include "stdafx.h"`?  It's not needed and in my experience, more trouble than its worth.

Comment: @Learner stdafx.h must come first otherwise everything is even worse

Comment: I am not 100% sure the answer, but one thing I would try adding: using namespace std;

Comment: @Jonathan Shudder ....

Comment: I know many tend to consider using namespace std; bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?s=1|3.9018 however, it would at least be a good debug step to see if it resolves the compiler errors here (especially since they include std:: in the error)

Comment: If none of the above works, I would take a look at the second (accepted) answer to the question here, it looks like it might be related to this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737092/shared-ptr-not-defined-when-including-from-managed-code

Comment: I tried these thing, add using namespace std and switch the order or iostream etc.. same error, never seen this error before.

Comment: Well for anyone reading, I just uninstalled VS and also the windows SDK(manually) now it works.