# How to change the value set to ${OutDir} flag in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I Am not able to edit the macro ${OutDir} in my c++ project.It contains a space in its value and hence is causing build to fail.What I want is to change it from `LIB Realease` to `LIB_Release` or something that does not contain a space. I did not get a satisfactory answer to this even after following links .[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349378/edit-includepath-macro-in-visual-studio-2010) [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hdf2d1z8(v=vs.100).aspx) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710084/visual-studio-where-to-define-custom-path-macros). If editing existing macros is not possible how to add new ones?

Comment: Why tagging with `C#` and `.NET`?

Answer (score 0):

$(OutDir) is set in the Properties of the project. Rightclick on the project -> properties -> configuation properties -> general -> output directory.

Nonetheless, VS builds do also work if the $(OutDir) contains spaces as the folder name gets protected by "" (as can be seen in configuration properties -> linker -> commandline)

Maybe you have some pre- or postbuild evens which use $(OutDir). If yes you should enclose it within "".